# Python Change a specific item in a JSON array

Tags: python, json, discord.py

Basically, I am creating a discord bot that monitors players Twitch Streams and adverts for them when they go live.

I created everything fine and am using a JSON file to store streamers Twitch names, discord ID, and if the bot already marked them as LIVE.

However, I am having difficulty updating the specific persons live status in the JSON file without overwritting the entire thing.

Here is the code from the start of the loop to the end:

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def live_notifs_loop():
    # Opens and reads the json file
    with open('streamers.json') as file:
        streamers = json.load(file)
    
    # Makes sure the json isn't empty before continuing.
    if streamers['streamers'] is not None:
        # Gets the guild, 'twitch streams' channel, and streaming role.
        guild = bot.get_guild(805833346960719)
        channel = bot.get_channel(845774787241312)
        role = get(guild.roles, id=845904634870366)
        # Loops through the json and gets the key,value which in this case is the user_id and twitch_name of
        # every item in the json.
        for streamer in streamers['streamers']:
            # Takes the given twitch_name and checks it using the checkuser function to see if they're live.
            # Returns either true or false.
            twitch_name = streamer['twitch_name']
            print(streamer['twitch_name'])
            status = checkuser(streamer['twitch_name'])
            print(status)
            titleStatus = checktitle(streamer['twitch_name'])
            print(titleStatus)
            isAlreadyLive = streamer['currently_live']
            print(streamer['currently_live'])

            # Gets the user using the collected user_id in the json
            user = bot.get_user(int(streamer['discord_id']))
            # Makes sure they're live
            
            
            if status is True:
            #     # Checks to see if the live message has already been sent.
                if isAlreadyLive:
                    break
                else:
                    async for member in guild.fetch_members(limit=None):
                        if member.id == int(streamer['discord_id']):
                            await member.add_roles(role)
                    await channel.send(
                        f":red_circle: **LIVE**\n{user.mention} is now streaming on Twitch!"
                        f"\nhttps://www.twitch.tv/{twitch_name}\n{titleStatus}")
                    
                    liveUpdate = {"currently_live": True}
                    
                    with open('streamers.json', 'r+') as writefile:
                        data = json.load(writefile)
                        data.update(liveUpdate)
                    break
```

My question is near the end of this code, as the rest of it seems to function fine.
How can I update the currently_live item in the array of the specific person and keep the other data the same?

Here is the JSON file for reference:

```
{
"streamers":[
    {"discord_id": "2500732809568583", "twitch_name": "Streamer1", "currently_live": true},{"discord_id": "3079686554661683", "twitch_name": "Streamer2", "currently_live": false}
]
}
```

Here is the updated JSON saving function as suggested below, still get an error where it overwrites the entire JSON file (Most likely due to my saving method of writing the file.

```
for updateStreamer in streamers['streamers']:
    if updateStreamer['twitch_name'] == twitch_name:
       updateStreamer['currently_live'] = False
       with open('streamers.json', 'w') as writeFile:
            writeFile.write(json.dumps(updateStreamer))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reach to that data and change it.

```
for streamer in streamers['streamers']:
    if streamer['twitch_name'] == 'your match':
        streamer['currently_live'] = False # or True whatever you want to put
```

And the streamers dictionary has your updated data without modifying other data.

Comment: This still erased my streamers json and replaced it with a single line:   {"discord_id": "307968655466168", "twitch_name": "Streamer1", "currently_live": false}

This is the updated code:

  
  

`for updateStreamer in streamers['streamers']:
                            if updateStreamer['twitch_name'] == twitch_name:
                                updateStreamer['currently_live'] = False
                                with open('streamers.json', 'w') as writeFile:
                                    writeFile.write(json.dumps(updateStreamer))`

Comment: I apologize for the above formatting  
apparently it's not working.

Comment: I added the new changes to my original post to make it easier to read.

Comment: Try to add a break after u write JSON file. And can you show me what exactly the error is.